# Generators of a Power of a Prime Ideal

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, where $\zeta_n$ is an nth root of unity. I know that in $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$, a prime ideal above a given prime $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ has the form $\mathfrak{p} = (p, f(\zeta_n))$, where $f$ is an irreducible polynomial in the factorization of $\Phi_n(x)$ modulo $p$. I have a question about the generators of $\mathfrak{p}^2$: is $f(\zeta_n)$ contained in $\mathfrak{p}^2?$ I know that $\mathfrak{p}^2$ is generated by $p^2, f(\zeta_n)^2,$ and $pf(\zeta_n)$, but I can't seem to prove that it doesn't also contain $f(\zeta_n)$.

Comment: The polynomial $f(x)$ is only defined modulo $p$, so $f(\zeta_n)$ doesn't really make any sense as an element of $K$. If you make a choice of $f(x)$ with this property, then the answer could depend on this choice. if $K = \mathbf{Q}(i)$, and $p = 5$, then $x^2+1 = (x+2)(x-2) \equiv (x+7)(x-7) \bmod 5$. If $f(x) = x - 2$, then $f(i)$ is divisible by $\mathfrak{p}= (i-2,5)$ but not by $\mathfrak{p}^2$; if $f(x) = x-7$, then $f(i)$ is divisible by $\mathfrak{p}^2$.

Comment: @user760870 I see! Thanks for the reply. In light of your comment, the question I'm interested in would become: is there always a choice of $f(x)$ modulo $p$ such that $f(\zeta_n)$ is **not** divisible by $\mathfrak{p}^2$?

Comment: The phrasing "choice of $f(x)$ modulo $p$" is strange, better to say choice of $f(x)$ given $f(x) \pmod p$. Anyway, this has little to do with cyclotomic fields and applies more generally.  Exercise 1: If $p$ is unramified, then either $f(x)$ or $f(x) - p$ works. Exercise 2: If $p$ is ramified, then any choice works.

Comment: Is the proof in the unramified case as follows: fix $f(x)$ and suppose both $f(\zeta_n)$ and $f(\zeta_n) - p$ are in $\mathfrak{p}^2$ . Then $f(\zeta_n) - (f(\zeta_n)-p) = p$ is in $\mathfrak{p}^2$ - a contradiction, . So at most one of $f(\zeta_n)$ and $f(\zeta_n) - p$ lie in  $\mathfrak{p}^2$.

Comment: Yes, exactly right.